# Getting different R and p values from ggplot stat_cor(method = "pearson") and cor(method = "pearson") in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing some analysis on localization of cells in tissue and tried to get the R and p value for correlation between two cell types, but I wound up getting different results when using the cor() function in R and the stat_cor() method in ggplot. Is this a known issue?

Here's the ggplot code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

lymph_plot <- ggplot(tumor_df, aes(
  x=`DENSITY [LYMPHOCYTE CELLS] IN [CANCER]_H & E`,
  y= CD8.Density*100000)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(group=1)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(colour = INDICATION)) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10', limits = c(50, 2000)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10') +
  expand_limits(y=10, x=10) +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(
    x ="Lymphocytes Density (H&E)", y = "CD8+ Cell Density (mIF)")
```

Here's the cor() code.

```
print(cor(tumor_df$`DENSITY [LYMPHOCYTE CELLS] IN [CANCER]_H & E`, tumor_df$CD8.Density, method = "pearson"))
```

Edit:
Here's the format of the dataframe I'm using.

```
> dput(tumor_df)
structure(list(CASE_ID = c("15H5131", "19H12892", "JO618", "JP755", 
"JQ480", "JS182", "JS20", "JS244", "JT68", "JX936", "KB784", 
"KB834", "KP860", "KU410", "KU43", "KU71", "KX782", "LC686", 
"LD239", "LE496", "LF014", "LH400", "LI988", "LK423", "LL075", 
"LO514", "LQ219", "LQ377", "LS028", "LS068", "LS601", "LT433", 
"LU095", "LU466", "LV399", "LV504", "LV676", "LW890", "LY363", 
"LY701", "LZ953", "MA239", "MB103", "MB864", "MD801", "MF985", 
"MG940", "MH024", "MI506", "MJ245", "MK566", "ML175", "ML585", 
"ML716", "ML778", "MO370", "MP960", "MR948", "MT774", "MT838", 
"MV097", "MV192", "MX356", "MY147", "MY275", "NA759", "NA850", 
"NC030", "NC532", "NC966", "ND177", "ND323", "ND559", "ND945", 
"NE902", "NF884", "NF975", "NI460", "NI853", "NK521", "NL792", 
"NM459", "NO436", "NP186", "NR211", "NR516", "NS701", "NV525", 
"OA874"), Class = c("Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor"
), INDICATION = c("NSCLC", "NSCLC", "OVR", "PANC", "OVR", "OVR", 
"OVR", "OVR", "OVR", "PANC", "OVR", "OVR", "OVR", "PANC", "OVR", 
"PANC", "OVR", "CRC", "PANC", "CRC", "NSCLC", "CRC", "NSCLC", 
"TNBC", "PANC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "OVR", "TNBC", "PANC", "TNBC", 
"NSCLC", "OVR", "TNBC", "OVR", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "TNBC", "OVR", 
"CRC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "PANC", "TNBC", "NSCLC", "CRC", "TNBC", 
"NSCLC", "NSCLC", "PANC", "TNBC", "PANC", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", "NSCLC", 
"CRC", "NSCLC", "TNBC", "CRC", "OVR", "PANC", "CRC", "PANC", 
"PANC", "CRC", "NSCLC", "CRC", "TNBC", "CRC", "NSCLC", "CRC", 
"TNBC", "TNBC", "PANC", "TNBC", "TNBC", "PANC", "CRC", "CRC", 
"OVR", "OVR", "CRC", "CRC", "NSCLC", "CRC", "TNBC", "CRC", "TNBC", 
"CRC"), Num.Detections_sum = c(5901, 37359, 1088030, 330721, 
483821, 174349, 52299, 1361272, 479786, 200334, 256729, 165490, 
218439, 583245, 825727, 65392, 1201815, 33946, 903, 503160, 69171, 
1006030, 497185, 41628, 9031, 281640, 74583, 86811, 111429, 327669, 
81946, 2158, 32653, 214451, 203494, 1074, 2160, 383, 2216, 808612, 
51708, 112841, 12030, 332154, 37546, 282376, 228134, 34732, 556, 
18177, 224601, 198323, 6204, 91514, 1208891, 136938, 10591, 358407, 
269502, 302369, 103695, 464752, 123386, 181522, 1487814, 26618, 
377606, 139368, 1047002, 29142, 785050, 75537, 31162, 2642, 20985, 
459318, 17168, 484998, 726218, 187358, 410256, 788088, 1015676, 
7174, 125102, 109797, 191448, 14333, 407490), Num.CD45._sum = c(436, 
11281, 3759, 61005, 17245, 593, 397, 66937, 19794, 1794, 4664, 
3768, 10717, 27158, 19882, 560, 59985, 96, 260, 680, 1328, 36866, 
35677, 624, 1140, 22339, 127, 567, 733, 8499, 3340, 415, 534, 
3715, 14224, 252, 171, 10, 108, 10338, 2524, 14931, 2690, 15919, 
5562, 2146, 53427, 3278, 10, 1023, 71417, 8573, 274, 4502, 249801, 
294, 3424, 11275, 10556, 1635, 21776, 8756, 5331, 3076, 14176, 
8083, 3324, 479, 4104, 3243, 10668, 4980, 7150, 526, 63, 9210, 
428, 3734, 20796, 1137, 20044, 30324, 3040, 300, 266, 3631, 960, 
350, 9620), Num.CD8._sum = c(58, 2715, 1839, 11040, 13013, 2177, 
274, 25881, 4612, 1576, 731, 1505, 6232, 12423, 24658, 67, 47139, 
12, 25, 550, 151, 39924, 12105, 579, 169, 8100, 99, 235, 1049, 
708, 4042, 20, 180, 608, 5807, 6, 11, 8, 31, 1376, 2409, 298, 
94, 10403, 6398, 576, 1670, 711, 16, 56, 77623, 7862, 26, 1506, 
113120, 740, 236, 8286, 3444, 1530, 1491, 5818, 327, 793, 3392, 
459, 5176, 241, 3954, 1111, 2736, 785, 1177, 135, 126, 4159, 
74, 3532, 17238, 4788, 62655, 19482, 9098, 74, 228, 884, 266, 
50, 2568), Num.Epithelial.Cell_sum = c(4705, 23226, 1079052, 
243355, 444713, 171285, 51498, 1260745, 451462, 182397, 250290, 
159371, 200704, 479319, 771269, 64482, 1080561, 28662, 395, 501080, 
62983, 926320, 381436, 39898, 7393, 217380, 74237, 85346, 107121, 
306770, 73529, 1634, 31687, 207250, 179925, 796, 1957, 364, 2077, 
795156, 46636, 97050, 9090, 300360, 24006, 270938, 120480, 28407, 
530, 16908, 75070, 178646, 5766, 82884, 817453, 135846, 6860, 
331558, 249138, 297591, 67293, 449460, 94132, 173363, 1469484, 
17314, 368662, 135642, 1037944, 24635, 770308, 67216, 21991, 
1556, 20672, 438168, 16490, 477380, 685668, 180681, 324676, 729548, 
1001082, 6761, 124388, 103363, 188644, 12877, 391600), Num.Stromal.Cell_sum = c(702, 
137, 3380, 15321, 8850, 294, 130, 7709, 3918, 14567, 1044, 846, 
786, 64345, 9918, 283, 14130, 5176, 223, 850, 4709, 2920, 67967, 
527, 329, 33821, 120, 663, 2526, 11692, 1035, 89, 252, 2878, 
3538, 20, 21, 1, 0, 1742, 139, 562, 156, 5472, 1580, 8716, 52557, 
2336, 0, 190, 491, 3242, 138, 2622, 28517, 58, 71, 7288, 6364, 
1613, 13135, 718, 23596, 4290, 762, 762, 444, 3006, 1000, 153, 
1338, 2556, 844, 425, 124, 7781, 176, 352, 2516, 752, 2881, 8734, 
2456, 39, 220, 1919, 1578, 1056, 3702), Area.Âµm.2_sum = c(761094.82, 
4829065.76, 154035854.41, 70287536.88, 81941973.3, 25635137.14, 
8516512.99, 158043941.99, 61033324.9, 37222365.74, 44037842.42, 
27472383.43, 33716614.28, 236497269.49, 166455372.15, 12285718.96, 
195936016.41, 3264917.12, 124446.33, 84009493.4, 16899796.58, 
154978558.6, 92478966.63, 6185602.18, 1093733.37, 66505662.15, 
15790751.54, 13120553.52, 19790626.76, 47450301.15, 15468284.13, 
421263.38, 6134573.09, 41012842.13, 36431119.05, 158546.07, 410882.99, 
44378.97, 540217.38, 143816301.62, 9715682.98, 23922757.72, 2227576.04, 
61060634.77, 4508707.54, 50675813.74, 28462720.15, 6198346.58, 
65031.07, 3553167.2, 25998493.44, 45381179.35, 745925.07, 13522309.85, 
175367306.16, 27294133.08, 1853163.37, 61037865.51, 48492641.76, 
53957530.05, 20803409.25, 81491186.28, 21961433.94, 32102217.24, 
301147198.37, 4135588.49, 79777441.5, 20646737.5, 214818182.21, 
3863035.6, 157219246.58, 11508709.2, 5751487.66, 341496.7, 2814197.24, 
218188655.24, 2833905.9, 100508011.76, 154872989.3, 25956162.02, 
71102584.81, 132817039.06, 169237437.56, 1030925.49, 23263643.46, 
18817789.09, 34495027.38, 3057204.81, 71854993.66), `DENSITY [FIBROBLAST CELLS] IN [CANCER]_H & E` = c(760.422790527344, 
2108.2890625, 198.287536621094, 29.0107536315918, 119.20027923584, 
253.682037353516, 186.139129638672, 39.3154373168945, 374.099914550781, 
15.7692899703979, 101.228172302246, 171.473251342773, 622.972534179688, 
48.0828552246094, 245.559112548828, 30.3591327667236, 422.793731689453, 
503.068176269531, 25.3702068328857, 195.042709350586, 350.258514404297, 
104.814002990723, 305.183319091797, 208.088287353516, 6.53217077255249, 
457.348602294922, 955.139831542969, 60.5157623291016, 752.118225097656, 
12.9543485641479, 904.97705078125, 2186.44067382812, 424.692901611328, 
293.632049560547, 142.075424194336, 2403.2109375, 200.60466003418, 
1445.04357910156, 704.592651367188, 98.2728729248047, 238.124160766602, 
403.703369140625, 5.08413791656494, 201.956176757812, 35.4216156005859, 
171.085403442383, 744.489685058594, 1845.89221191406, 3036.35961914062, 
3.91726970672607, 174.417343139648, 19.2679862976074, 2572.59350585938, 
2075.17260742188, 1761.56372070312, 530.343566894531, 469.048553466797, 
105.152481079102, 372.755401611328, 42.1557388305664, 46.1358680725098, 
114.413551330566, 30.1332740783691, 18.2827758789062, 92.9767379760742, 
580.865905761719, 63.2788276672363, 153.221618652344, 120.366493225098, 
1398.96228027344, 48.3088569641113, 563.661865234375, 421.820922851562, 
2.0244710445404, 680.86767578125, 74.682243347168, 1.86469495296478, 
142.553115844727, 210.959884643555, 1027.02014160156, 229.699005126953, 
134.904388427734, 178.635925292969, 1714.06323242188, 124.771255493164, 
470.787567138672, 154.59521484375, 846.917846679688, 72.37646484375
), `DENSITY [FIBROBLAST CELLS] IN [STROMA]_H & E` = c(2469.5546875, 
3242.470703125, 3427.27563476562, 2051.97007106836, 2943.18627929688, 
5594.6552734375, 2996.83959960938, 3562.73266601562, 3073.64599609375, 
2037.46164482512, 3154.35131835938, 3481.77563476562, 2904.92358398438, 
1918.51181199753, 4065.93286132812, 1461.74489163726, 2256.37915039062, 
2921.10815429688, 1768.16606300715, 2784.41796875, 1393.67541503906, 
2302.8759765625, 2355.28466796875, 1886.18225097656, 910.866484446677, 
1247.40405273438, 1953.89611816406, 2478.4931640625, 1197.625, 
2500.25560601867, 1523.48229980469, 3299.90454101562, 1805.95849609375, 
1318.00305175781, 1881.91369628906, 3177.06176757812, 1554.04357910156, 
1231.57116699219, 2150.54150390625, 2897.68334960938, 1217.8310546875, 
1750.5, 391.546184760955, 1457.74914550781, 530.693054199219, 
2952.85766601562, 1512.5166015625, 2791.45141601562, 4123.44873046875, 
442.195553785201, 755.353576660156, 1087.60847038999, 3646.01977539062, 
3401.26416015625, 3055.494140625, 2482.173828125, 992.778625488281, 
1182.71264648438, 1922.55200195312, 2499.09716796875, 1723.52200545516, 
1963.40124511719, 2108.10652603417, 2277.50282186154, 2392.40063476562, 
1564.78869628906, 1577.751953125, 1647.94116210938, 3057.916015625, 
2546.873046875, 1287.73791503906, 1890.482421875, 1175.67883300781, 
1206.50049245462, 2022.73388671875, 1304.52917480469, 870.795979804125, 
2878.15112304688, 3010.56176757812, 2206.03881835938, 1232.70837402344, 
2673.59106445312, 2751.03051757812, 2469.39916992188, 2022.25671386719, 
1585.89208984375, 2399.47045898438, 2025.78442382812, 3576.57592773438
), `DENSITY [IMMUNE CELLS] IN [CANCER]_H & E` = c(899.382202148438, 
741.674560546875, 64.9308700561523, 189.890121459961, 208.703155517578, 
116.636100769043, 313.484161376953, 632.217102050781, 309.154449462891, 
176.205825805664, 145.886260986328, 202.532867431641, 790.525573730469, 
506.786346435547, 180.900207519531, 212.979553222656, 431.092712402344, 
423.122314453125, 341.344604492188, 159.135498046875, 418.315216064453, 
738.974426269531, 438.305541992188, 238.498245239258, 1205.65209960938, 
257.157135009766, 137.711212158203, 488.391540527344, 97.0711288452148, 
109.661682128906, 402.953277587891, 2023.15454101562, 1051.33471679688, 
127.84497833252, 764.593078613281, 593.304626464844, 751.526428222656, 
1023.57250976562, 1213.2451171875, 136.928100585938, 402.392883300781, 
378.592163085938, 516.548400878906, 326.045440673828, 677.598876953125, 
324.144348144531, 583.008056640625, 872.110961914062, 1107.84948730469, 
200.986068725586, 1956.58959960938, 406.707427978516, 881.810607910156, 
311.328033447266, 1044.12670898438, 245.519348144531, 975.053588867188, 
455.367889404297, 317.19775390625, 54.6335296630859, 274.043487548828, 
412.648468017578, 331.307983398438, 167.282760620117, 249.295822143555, 
1395.29919433594, 325.700927734375, 130.08154296875, 145.315643310547, 
582.824951171875, 340.837921142578, 621.3369140625, 306.778839111328, 
983.892883300781, 294.510833740234, 112.877532958984, 252.666168212891, 
162.969329833984, 219.78596496582, 532.055603027344, 1725.62524414062, 
418.485137939453, 335.359344482422, 345.713958740234, 361.223785400391, 
208.597702026367, 174.203567504883, 430.895294189453, 143.316024780273
), `DENSITY [IMMUNE CELLS] IN [STROMA]_H & E` = c(4844.66748046875, 
2780.29711914062, 772.387268066406, 922.873962402344, 1565.55029296875, 
479.540649414062, 2004.30603027344, 5987.75537109375, 1585.70031738281, 
489.860931396484, 1971.50122070312, 1934.13562011719, 3612.6875, 
302.677368164062, 1191.33166503906, 530.032592773438, 2197.2421875, 
1473.25378417969, 677.040283203125, 1925.66516113281, 2472.22094726562, 
3159.8603515625, 2732.1240234375, 4585.43505859375, 596.889770507812, 
2685.6357421875, 404.194458007812, 2122.08520507812, 412.23828125, 
466.900970458984, 1044.53442382812, 3423.02319335938, 2782.72607421875, 
2010.72314453125, 4228.16748046875, 2123.93774414062, 4622.62109375, 
2487.08959960938, 2696.74560546875, 3664.09399414062, 3083.15698242188, 
2926.13256835938, 2274.126953125, 2681.99658203125, 7549.005859375, 
2231.23022460938, 3826.53857421875, 3542.97973632812, 1539.4208984375, 
567.251892089844, 9714.6982421875, 812.825927734375, 1964.24328613281, 
1568.70263671875, 1989.48559570312, 607.440551757812, 7062.72021484375, 
1238.54272460938, 1515.87854003906, 2066.95385742188, 646.867309570312, 
4032.39086914062, 393.719055175781, 687.686096191406, 2119.71166992188, 
5677.37451171875, 5368.431640625, 2024.16796875, 2692.32568359375, 
5179.40673828125, 5320.4921875, 6973.734375, 2159.27221679688, 
1191.04907226562, 1322.24670410156, 1224.60327148438, 1015.76025390625, 
2292.21875, 961.14404296875, 2405.896484375, 5487.07666015625, 
2984.76879882812, 2238.18432617188, 3429.33227539062, 1809.34521484375, 
1655.57897949219, 1799.47534179688, 3454.91943359375, 2944.587890625
), `DENSITY [LYMPHOCYTE CELLS] IN [CANCER]_H & E` = c(682.135803222656, 
607.581420898438, 48.8832015991211, 57.9874382019043, 123.743446350098, 
66.0720062255859, 51.4448509216309, 163.715621948242, 56.5456199645996, 
65.9273529052734, 68.6016998291016, 105.602676391602, 285.455261230469, 
191.460357666016, 102.707588195801, 83.2237548828125, 154.944519042969, 
102.615295410156, 274.459503173828, 60.9267921447754, 177.20149230957, 
306.696838378906, 315.561553955078, 205.984451293945, 641.832458496094, 
209.876403808594, 94.3735198974609, 35.7229614257812, 84.8701324462891, 
65.8974533081055, 335.738830566406, 992.490905761719, 110.728866577148, 
111.769119262695, 247.964462280273, 472.446258544922, 337.698913574219, 
782.73193359375, 148.439453125, 52.5642547607422, 361.891540527344, 
339.760894775391, 232.345092773438, 293.986083984375, 646.116882324219, 
108.07576751709, 510.750640869141, 624.392761230469, 745.87890625, 
142.227020263672, 1521.93518066406, 269.588684082031, 727.688842773438, 
214.217666625977, 920.371948242188, 55.7181930541992, 642.079345703125, 
276.499938964844, 95.8276290893555, 29.1596393585205, 77.4295806884766, 
154.030990600586, 158.463088989258, 80.5091781616211, 52.2104225158691, 
434.504302978516, 111.191497802734, 113.865737915039, 61.051456451416, 
508.99853515625, 119.182960510254, 453.73876953125, 224.495834350586, 
878.620422363281, 247.941055297852, 92.0842971801758, 209.778182983398, 
63.6812896728516, 91.8022994995117, 175.209655761719, 596.312927246094, 
137.399658203125, 76.0009994506836, 199.902633666992, 32.9629364013672, 
157.339859008789, 55.836009979248, 286.712677001953, 72.2515182495117
), `DENSITY [LYMPHOCYTE CELLS] IN [STROMA]_H & E` = c(3508.41552734375, 
2032.57263183594, 314.994537353516, 598.148010253906, 503.876220703125, 
221.345977783203, 331.927276611328, 2173.10424804688, 420.103302001953, 
371.943634033203, 503.681518554688, 531.963562011719, 1424.5400390625, 
222.763793945312, 358.406005859375, 373.721710205078, 477.317626953125, 
556.652038574219, 639.836791992188, 789.373352050781, 937.607238769531, 
1106.38220214844, 1753.04370117188, 3722.67114257812, 522.135070800781, 
2256.2001953125, 327.993499755859, 555.642578125, 352.152038574219, 
383.125885009766, 876.350830078125, 2624.37182617188, 774.757568359375, 
1675.19970703125, 1079.525390625, 1182.84814453125, 2462.76391601562, 
2028.67150878906, 578.721557617188, 1613.83056640625, 2481.4970703125, 
2165.44799804688, 1375.1982421875, 1984.73168945312, 6355.97509765625, 
915.85400390625, 3147.75512695312, 2362.23388671875, 691.168579101562, 
513.270751953125, 6183.8994140625, 648.486694335938, 1252.37805175781, 
992.166625976562, 1358.26330566406, 259.380096435547, 4001.76391601562, 
777.892272949219, 470.936401367188, 616.552368164062, 508.394653320312, 
1704.31884765625, 288.900268554688, 496.774810791016, 603.010437011719, 
2635.56567382812, 950.036560058594, 1552.30212402344, 776.038635253906, 
3746.59838867188, 1759.69421386719, 4850.57177734375, 1565.390625, 
1122.16137695312, 1054.7119140625, 890.909423828125, 920.801086425781, 
854.787475585938, 372.365142822266, 657.544250488281, 1802.64367675781, 
799.288391113281, 769.309753417969, 1582.2705078125, 438.481597900391, 
1239.93176269531, 593.871520996094, 2088.63525390625, 1067.08471679688
), `AREA (MM2) OF [CANCER] IN [TISSUE]_H & E` = c(1.11854553222656, 
14.5346765518188, 131.047058105469, 58.7023696899414, 77.9192810058594, 
33.6602478027344, 7.89194583892822, 167.186248779297, 79.8824005126953, 
37.5413246154785, 41.8065452575684, 24.7910385131836, 40.6438484191895, 
5.74009132385254, 146.522766113281, 32.2143592834473, 185.324401855469, 
8.29311084747314, 0.433579444885254, 54.5572814941406, 42.1046142578125, 
82.6320877075195, 130.148941040039, 5.22854995727539, 5.3580961227417, 
129.37614440918, 14.0293588638306, 15.004355430603, 20.4901294708252, 
57.7412261962891, 5.99573230743408, 0.314360558986664, 9.32909393310547, 
39.3758125305176, 39.3241844177246, 0.273046940565109, 0.51229065656662, 
0.0166084952652454, 0.505256474018097, 75.8500213623047, 8.39478015899658, 
19.7521266937256, 1.9669017791748, 50.6248435974121, 3.39876580238342, 
36.1690711975098, 26.8761291503906, 19.3243751525879, 0.18233522772789, 
3.31863808631897, 10.0792732238769, 49.0450820922852, 1.02516353130341, 
89.0636138916016, 199.450881958008, 36.7384490966797, 0.837902665138245, 
67.1501007080078, 34.8646850585938, 52.0925521850586, 11.1843566894531, 
45.2830963134766, 18.9823379516602, 21.5503368377686, 131.333923339844, 
2.70192956924439, 55.1211242675781, 16.8970928192139, 104.81322479248, 
3.46759343147278, 91.5567092895508, 9.3974781036377, 5.18940591812134, 
0.493956208229065, 4.63819932937622, 156.877990722656, 3.21768450737, 
55.4951057434082, 90.0739974975586, 27.2302360534668, 66.778694152832, 
62.5183525085449, 93.8277130126953, 1.70082807540894, 16.806755065918, 
30.8440608978271, 16.7275562286377, 2.42054176330566, 32.0131683349609
), `AREA (MM2) OF [STROMA] IN [TISSUE]_H & E` = c(0.497660547494888, 
27.0179767608643, 23.9750194549561, 137.143325805664, 75.1831512451172, 
23.6372032165527, 8.00476551055908, 62.9132270812988, 189.034469604492, 
88.1719665527344, 35.5581817626953, 26.5488109588623, 73.4552841186523, 
189.4921875, 68.9497375488281, 188.854431152344, 98.2804718017578, 
21.1029510498047, 28.0618438720703, 46.5267791748047, 14.1338500976562, 
48.717342376709, 19.374303817749, 12.959511756897, 28.7473526000977, 
57.7222747802734, 66.1933898925781, 12.1013040542603, 90.2536239624023, 
184.505935668945, 67.1409225463867, 0.617290556430817, 25.0581607818604, 
86.0506362915039, 38.0389404296875, 0.847953259944916, 0.0759309455752373, 
0.292309522628784, 2.27570581436157, 57.5735778808594, 19.9847106933594, 
37.2624969482422, 2.08915328979492, 61.1044807434082, 0.243078365921974, 
46.0750274658203, 44.5886001586914, 37.7244606018066, 0.509282410144806, 
2.22299838066101, 32.8415756225586, 111.269821166992, 2.45692563056946, 
139.373764038086, 271.533508300781, 55.9988975524902, 0.750419080257416, 
28.6942043304443, 116.707901000977, 13.470064163208, 146.144348144531, 
47.969310760498, 107.919593811035, 58.2155151367188, 61.1979446411133, 
1.59510350227356, 40.8815841674805, 12.9549522399902, 107.204711914062, 
4.22596645355225, 37.9378433227539, 27.1015472412109, 18.9499034881592, 
1.55325257778168, 10.0472936630249, 40.6000862121582, 1.97979784011841, 
33.4492492675781, 105.718811035156, 45.3672866821289, 54.848331451416, 
88.4574356079102, 36.8629150390625, 3.85964345932007, 23.6201477050781, 
33.9518699645996, 15.6767921447754, 13.8104524612427, 13.4337978363037
), CD45.Density = c(0.000572858977019447, 0.00233606261762731, 
2.44034092867405e-05, 0.000867934810465078, 0.000210453804143377, 
2.31323123711598e-05, 4.66153225464639e-05, 0.00042353410802823, 
0.000324314627007974, 4.81968290927873e-05, 0.000105908912510251, 
0.000137155919128783, 0.000317855165142044, 0.000114834306791641, 
0.00011944342644636, 4.55813780067129e-05, 0.000306145858730129, 
2.94035028981073e-05, 0.00208925405835592, 8.0943233017996e-06, 
7.85808275095818e-05, 0.000237878067347053, 0.000385785020098034, 
0.00010087942642312, 0.00104230156203426, 0.000335896212109212, 
8.04268243207378e-06, 4.32146402311234e-05, 3.70377355345567e-05, 
0.000179113720967396, 0.00021592569492063, 0.000985131914385722, 
8.70476220864458e-05, 9.05813839534558e-05, 0.000390435440110369, 
0.0015894433712548, 0.000416176877996337, 0.000225331953400451, 
0.000199919521286042, 7.18833670699979e-05, 0.000259786162763413, 
0.000624133729679389, 0.0012075906508673, 0.000260708066006239, 
0.00123361294798021, 4.23476179585469e-05, 0.00187708693049845, 
0.000528850711668337, 0.000153772650519206, 0.000287912147787473, 
0.00274696686424612, 0.00018891091247059, 0.000367329120604567, 
0.000332931285404616, 0.00142444452999745, 1.07715456335717e-05, 
0.0018476514566549, 0.000184721400491188, 0.000217682510518685, 
3.03016094043764e-05, 0.00104675150780875, 0.000107447202571267, 
0.00024274371220771, 9.58189266804675e-05, 4.70733251935582e-05, 
0.00195449813721674, 4.16659137909305e-05, 2.31997912503126e-05, 
1.91045281073464e-05, 0.000839495240478757, 6.78542877673164e-05, 
0.000432715773198961, 0.00124315662706299, 0.00154027842728788, 
2.23864905787485e-05, 4.22111772487406e-05, 0.000151028303374505, 
3.71512671936671e-05, 0.000134277772347486, 4.38046271680654e-05, 
0.000281902550428532, 0.00022831407938782, 1.79629285566453e-05, 
0.000291000661939206, 1.14341504785081e-05, 0.000192955717732513, 
2.78300982174782e-05, 0.000114483661302365, 0.000133880743842515
), CD8.Density = c(7.62060107044218e-05, 0.000562220548431712, 
1.19387788449896e-05, 0.000157069097738455, 0.000158807500917237, 
8.4922502583499e-05, 3.21727918834537e-05, 0.000163758254028095, 
7.55652753238747e-05, 4.234013525654e-05, 1.65993600010706e-05, 
5.47822872316397e-05, 0.000184834691533565, 5.25291477013238e-05, 
0.000148135801695722, 5.45348629723172e-06, 0.000240583639821281, 
3.67543786226341e-06, 0.000200889813303454, 6.54687914116144e-06, 
8.93501879062263e-06, 0.000257609829131551, 0.000130894628704395, 
9.36044677868372e-05, 0.000154516635073501, 0.000121794141102315, 
6.26949260452996e-06, 1.79108297254215e-05, 5.30048902806957e-05, 
1.49208747434894e-05, 0.000261308879900954, 4.74762368378661e-05, 
2.93418950853188e-05, 1.48246248839034e-05, 0.000159396695776217, 
3.7843889791781e-05, 2.67716120348521e-05, 0.000180265562720361, 
5.73843070358084e-05, 9.56776098745571e-06, 0.000247949629990912, 
1.24567578490696e-05, 4.21983350117197e-05, 0.000170371632053703, 
0.00141903193836343, 1.13663690326761e-05, 5.86732396341254e-05, 
0.000114708009760887, 0.000246036240830729, 1.57605867801549e-05, 
0.00298567300367386, 0.000173243624617261, 3.48560479405793e-05, 
0.000111371505068714, 0.00064504611764289, 2.71120536355207e-05, 
0.000127349808344204, 0.000135751798179156, 7.10210843336822e-05, 
2.8355634488499e-05, 7.16709449918647e-05, 7.13942239104192e-05, 
1.48897381151606e-05, 2.4702343581798e-05, 1.12635947415738e-05, 
0.000110987831867189, 6.48804963242648e-05, 1.16725463284454e-05, 
1.84062631911422e-05, 0.000287597660244187, 1.74024495061284e-05, 
6.82092132452178e-05, 0.000204642706301138, 0.000395318607763999, 
4.4772981157497e-05, 1.90614860127592e-05, 2.61123702096107e-05, 
3.51414771633724e-05, 0.000111304108469223, 0.000184464867968951, 
0.000881191593349614, 0.000146682986895974, 5.37587907922233e-05, 
7.17801632783374e-05, 9.80070041014977e-06, 4.69768257988271e-05, 
7.71125638109292e-06, 1.63548087574807e-05, 3.57386434706423e-05
), Immune.Cell.Density = c(0.000649064987723869, 0.00289828316605902, 
3.634218813173e-05, 0.00102500390820353, 0.000369261305060614, 
0.000108054814954659, 7.87881144299176e-05, 0.000587292362056326, 
0.000399879902331849, 9.05369643493272e-05, 0.000122508272511322, 
0.000191938206360423, 0.000502689856675609, 0.000167363454492965, 
0.000267579228142082, 5.10348643039446e-05, 0.000546729498551409, 
3.30789407603707e-05, 0.00229014387165937, 1.4641202442961e-05, 
8.75158463002044e-05, 0.000495487896478604, 0.000516679648802429, 
0.000194483894209957, 0.00119681819710776, 0.000457690353211527, 
1.43121750366037e-05, 6.11254699565449e-05, 9.00426258152523e-05, 
0.000194034595710885, 0.000477234574821584, 0.00103260815122359, 
0.000116389517171765, 0.000105406008837359, 0.000549832135886586, 
0.00162728726104658, 0.000442948490031189, 0.000405597516120811, 
0.000257303828321851, 8.14511280574537e-05, 0.000507735792754325, 
0.000636590487528459, 0.00124978898587902, 0.000431079698059942, 
0.00265264488634364, 5.3713986991223e-05, 0.00193576017013258, 
0.000643558721429223, 0.000399808891349935, 0.000303672734567627, 
0.00573263986791998, 0.000362154537087851, 0.000402185168545146, 
0.00044430279047333, 0.00206949064764034, 3.78835992690924e-05, 
0.0019750012649991, 0.000320473198670345, 0.000288703594852367, 
5.86572438928753e-05, 0.00111842245280061, 0.000178841426481686, 
0.000257633450322871, 0.000120521270262266, 5.8336919935132e-05, 
0.00206548596908393, 0.000106546410115195, 3.48723375787579e-05, 
3.75107912984886e-05, 0.00112709290072294, 8.52567372734448e-05, 
0.000500924986444179, 0.00144779933336413, 0.00193559703505188, 
6.71594717362455e-05, 6.12726632614998e-05, 0.000177140673584116, 
7.22927443570395e-05, 0.000245581880816709, 0.000228269495137016, 
0.00116309414377815, 0.000374997066283793, 7.17217193488686e-05, 
0.000362780825217543, 2.12348508886578e-05, 0.00023993254353134, 
3.55413545985711e-05, 0.000130838470059845, 0.000169619387313157
)), row.names = c(NA, -89L), class = "data.frame")
```

The output of cor() is R = 0.66 and p = 2.4e-12.

The output of stat_cor() is R = 0.61 and p = 5e-10.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What are the values you are getting? How different are they?

Comment: Just added the extra info. The output of cor() is R = 0.66 and p = 2.4e-12, while the output of stat_cor() is R = 0.61 and p = 5e-10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove your `scale_*_continuous` commands you get the same value. The issue is that ggpubr is using the transformed log10 values to calculate the correlation. Also the `limits = c(50, 2000)` is dropping some of your data because you have 4 values less than 50. So this is where it's getting the p-value from

```
result <- with(subset(tumor_df, `DENSITY [LYMPHOCYTE CELLS] IN [CANCER]_H & E`>50), 
      cor.test(log10(`DENSITY [LYMPHOCYTE CELLS] IN [CANCER]_H & E`), log10(CD8.Density)*100000, method = "pearson")
)

result$estimate |> signif(2)
#  cor 
# 0.61 
result$p.value |> signif(2)
# [1] 5e-10
```

There is a [github issue discouraging the use of scale_*_continuous](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/36)